# Flash AS3, reduce noise from laptop mic input

Tags: flash

I'm trying to create an app where user can record their sound through mic input in flash AS3. Everything is ok when user is using a headset mic, but if user recorded their voice through laptop mic, the result really s**k. There are a lot of distortions. Is there a work around for this?

I've tried mic.gain = 50 just to reduce the sound input. I've also set the mic volume to 50 also. But nothing seem to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: does the mic in question sound good when it's recorded by something other than flash?  the answers that come to mind are: "don't use the laptop mic" and "write a function to process the bytestream input and try to reverse the distortion";  but the one isn't helpful, and the 2nd one is something a crazy person would do...

Comment: Have you looked at using the "enhanced" Microphone? It has some features (acoustic echo cancellation) that may help. Granted echo canceling technically should not help with distortion, but I've used the built in mic on MacBook laptops quite a bit (w/echo canceling) and never noticed any issue.

Comment: Also, the OS usually has some settings for the microphone that you may want to look at. For example, if your OS has set the "gain" on the mic to be very high, you might reduce that...

Comment: Well, i tried using windows audio recorder, it sounded 'normal'. But when i'm using flash it's like way toooooo many voices are recorded and it causes distortion. I think the prob is in my coding. I (think) know the prob is probably in the mic.gain, it keeps giving me mic.gain = 100 even though i've set it to 50.

Comment: @goofy any luck solving this one? I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this setting

```
mic.gain = 40;
mic.rate = 16;
mic.setSilenceLevel(5, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres nothing wrong with either your either your application or your apps settings, the noise you hear when you are using your systems mic is from the rotating fan of your system especially if its a laptop and the mic is located on the board and not the monitor